# htcaccess external redirect is not excluding URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, external

I'm trying to exclude few URI from htaccess based redirection

My htaccess directives are bellow

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on    
        #
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule !=/test$ http://domain2.com [L,R=301,NC]
        #


          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
```

What wrong in this? Any suggesion?

I have tried in a different way as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com? [R=301,L]

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

While doing external redirection, exclusion of the the URI, test is not in effect. If I'm doing an internal rewrite, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test
# Add next line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This worked for excluding test URI, but domain1.com is not redirecting as index.php is in exclusion.

Comment: Conditions are only valid for the next rule. In this case, for the external redirect. Don't apply to other rules. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test.